# Bootstrap Wordpress theme dev - How to use WP loop to generate span6 in a span12 layout

Tags: wordpress, gridview, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on a wp theme project and i am trying implement the loop on a class = "span6" in a 12 grid layout, such that it will generate a 2 col magazine grid structure of all my wp post. but the different span six wont align properly, only the first two aligned well. in a static page, i would normally implement the grid layout like so:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
</div>
...and so on
```

however, since the famous wp loop will only need one span6 i cant do this method.

what can i do to make the other span6 generated align properly?

i noticed the problem came from the `.row-fluid` left margin, i also checked a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469838/twitter-bootstrap-position-issue-with-row-fluid), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554580/grid-layout-default-on-wordpress-theme) and many more... but none has answered my question with respect to generating span6 in a wp loop

this is what my page looks like:

```
<div class="span8">
   <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
   <article class="span6">
       <div>
         //content goes in here
       </div>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><h3>Sorry, No Post Available.</h3></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="span4">
 <?php get_sidebar()?>
</div>
```

my current output looks like this
`enter code here`[image]

but what i really want is some thing like this: 
`enter code here`[image]

Any help please?

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean "however, since the famous wp loop will only need one span6 i cant do this method." the so called famous loop is php code `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` which starts it and `<?php endwhile; else: ?><?php endif; ?>` which ends it, you can put your own divs in between the start and finish

Comment: my main problem is how the loop displays the posts, they dont align after the first line... i guess its a bootstrap thing, i just want to know if there is better way to implement the loop of a bootstrap span6 as seen in the images.

Comment: you dont have a working link to this by chance?

Comment: thanks for responding to this, with respect to a working link, sadly, i'm working locally and currently dont have any online server i can upload the code for real time testing. is there any way around this outside using a counter?

Comment: how are you generating the square boxes, i mean the image with text underneath?

Comment: hi... all the content generated are embedded inside  the <article> tag... my problem is... it just wont align... its bootstraps `.row-fluid` `left-margin: 2.3453%` thats my major problem here from what i can see... do you have a fix around it?

Comment: cant you just adjust the css then?

Comment: if i do... it will trash my responsive layout... and the main reason for using bootstrap is its responsiveness

Comment: if you create a new class and add new properties it wont "trash" the layout

Comment: did that already... and it had no effect on it... apparently, bootstrap's css rules took precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do in a situation like this is using a `$counter` variable. Place this after your `the_post();`

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
<?php
    //echo post here
    the_title();
    the_content();
?>

</div> <!-- close .post div -->

<?php
    $counter++;
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
    echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }
?>


<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The CSS you'd use for the code above would be:

```
.post{
    float:left;
    width:300px; /* width of the post */
}
```

I assume that's what you're looking for?

Comment: the problem with this counter method is that it only displays two post and then stops the loop from generating more post... it would be cool if it didnt stop at only 2 post display. I have already seen this method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048062/breaking-a-wordpress-loop-then-re-entering-after-inserting-a-div but it only displays a number of loops and stops... and when i tried it, still didnt given me my desired output... :(

Comment: Edited my answer above with more explanation, the loop above will loop through all posts (of the specified page) not only the first 2.

Comment: thanks alot @user2019515 ... it works! not very pretty for fluid layout but it works... thanks