# how to divide post blog side by side in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using Admired theme in wordpress. and i used "pages posts" Plugin for view posts for blog.
in that blog post shows only row by row.
i want to show posts side by side (like left side,right side.). how to achieve that. please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here:
[Bootstrap Wordpress theme dev - How to use WP loop to generate span6 in a span12 layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120444/bootstrap-wordpress-theme-dev-how-to-use-wp-loop-to-generate-span6-in-a-span12/15125341#15125341)

You won't need a plugin in that case, which is recommended for performance.